# How to send inputs from google spreadsheet sidebar into sheet script function?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to have 3 text fields with labels and a button on sidebar, clicking the button should send content of text fields to spreadsheet script function for further processing. I know how to create and display the sidebar, also how to trigger script function with button click but have no idea how to send text fields content.

```
// SidePanel.html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick='f1()'>Update the address</button>
<script>
  function f1() {
    google.script.run.getAddress();
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>

// display sidebar in gs
function showSidebar(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SidePanel').setTitle('Helper').setWidth(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Here is an example that will help you understand how to send values from the sidebar to the google sheet

Html Code:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <button onclick='f1()'>Update the address</button>
    <!-- Create a input field to except a value form user, in this case there name -->
    Your Name:
    <input type="text" id="name"><br>
    <!-- Create a button to send the value to the spreadsheet -->
    <button onclick='sendName()'>Send Name</button>
<script>

  function f1() {
    google.script.run.getAddress();
  }

  function sendName(){
   //Get the value of the input field 
   var name = document.getElementById("name").value
   //Log the value of input field in the web browser console (usually used for debugging)
   console.log(name)
   //Send the value of the text field as a arugment to the server side function.
   google.script.run.enterName(name)
  }
</script>
  </body>
</html>
```

The HTML code above use the [input field](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_form_elements.asp) to get values from the user. You can access the value of the input field using [DOM methods](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_methods.asp). The value of the text field is stored in the `var name` in `function sendNames()`. This is passed to the google script function as an argument `google.script.run.enterName(name)`.

Your google script (aka server-side code)

```
function showSidebar(){
  var html = HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('SO_sideBar_Example').setTitle('Helper').setWidth(100);
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(html);
}

// Sets the value of A1 cell to value entered in the input field in the side bar!
function enterName(name){
 var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
 var sheet = ss.getActiveSheet()
 sheet.getRange("A1").setValue(name) 
}
```

In the above server side code,`function enterName()` receives the user input in the argument `name`, which is entered in cell A1.

It is good practice to use withSuccessHandler() and withFailureHandler() as detailed [here](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run#methods). To handle the success or failure of the server side code.

Comment: Ok, but I want all three inputs to be send with one click (there is no separate button for each field). In your example, can gs enterName function handle 3 parameters? ie function enterName(name, address, city) and google.script.run.enterName(name, address, city) respectively?

Comment: I did a test according to my speculation and it worked well. Thank you very much for your help Jack.